# Cannot read property of undefined - method call within a class

Tags: typescript, this

I have a typescript class that contains the following

```
getOrgList(oo: fhir.Organization) {
    var olist: orgRoles[] = [];
    var filtered = oo.extension.filter(this.getRoleExt);

    filtered.forEach(function (value) {
        var org = new orgRoles();
        value.extension.forEach(function (innerValue) {
            switch (innerValue.url) {
                case 'role':
                    org.roleName = innerValue.valueCoding.display;
                    break;
                case 'primaryRole':
                    org.primaryRole = innerValue.valueBoolean;
                    break;
                case 'activePeriod':
                    var periodType = innerValue.valuePeriod.extension[0].valueString;
                    var periodExt = innerValue.valuePeriod;
                    var periodDisplay= this.getPeriodDisplay(periodExt);
                    break;
                case 'status':
                    org.activeStatus = innerValue.valueString;
                    break;
            }
        });

        olist.push(org);
    });

    return olist;
}
```

This is currently failing on the line

```
var periodDisplay= this.getPeriodDisplay(periodExt);
```

With an error

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPeriodDisplay' of undefined
```

However, getPeriodDisplay is defined as the next method in the same class.

```
getPeriodDisplay(pp) {
    return "++++";
}
```

I have other code that calls getPeriodDisplay() from outside the class, but calling it from a different method within the class seems to cause the problem

Any ideas on how I should address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch regular functions for arrow functions to have access to correct `this` (class instance):

```
getOrgList(oo: fhir.Organization) {
    var olist: orgRoles[] = [];
    var filtered = oo.extension.filter(this.getRoleExt);

    filtered.forEach((value) => {
        var org = new orgRoles();
        value.extension.forEach((innerValue) => {
            switch (innerValue.url) {
                case 'role':
                    org.roleName = innerValue.valueCoding.display;
                    break;
                case 'primaryRole':
                    org.primaryRole = innerValue.valueBoolean;
                    break;
                case 'activePeriod':
                    var periodType = innerValue.valuePeriod.extension[0].valueString;
                    var periodExt = innerValue.valuePeriod;
                    var periodDisplay= this.getPeriodDisplay(periodExt);
                    break;
                case 'status':
                    org.activeStatus = innerValue.valueString;
                    break;
            }
        });

        olist.push(org);
    });

    return olist;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @grassator. - thanks that had me puzzled for hours. I guess I'll try and use arrow functions as my default from now on.